# If I can get a set with n vectors into reduced row echelon form, doesn't that mean that the set is a basis for Rn?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let's say I have 3 vectors that are all in R3. If I can use Gaussian elimination to get these vectors into reduced row echelon form, it is to my understanding that this mean that the set spans R3. Does this also mean that the set is a basis for R3?

Comment: The non null rows of row echelon matrix form a basis for the row space of the original matrix.

Comment: No zero rows in the reduced row echelon form means the three vectors are linearly independent and they form one basis for R3. Any three linearly independent vectors in R3 form a basis for R3.

Comment: Thanks! Just want to make sure I have all my facts straight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. As $R^3$ has dimension 3, any set of three vectors $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ that spans $R^3$ must also be linearly independent. Thus as your three vectors span $R^3$, they must also be linearly independent. Hence they must form a basis for $R^3$.